# 4N35 opto isolator with ESP32

Tags: opto-isolator, esp32, sensing

I had an old Arduino setup where I used this chip to interface with another circuit which had some LEDs. The goal of the project was to signal the Arduino if the external circuit turned an LED on.

In the old setup Pin 1,2 of the 4N35 was simply connected parallel with the device's LEDs and the other end to the Arduinos which did `DigitalRead()` on it.

Has anyone successfully used this chip with ESP32 to do the same or is there a better solution to interface with an external circuit board?

Comment: what is your specific question? ... this is a Q&A site, not a forum ... `Anyone successfully used ....?` is not a question about electronics design

Comment: Was there a resistor in the Arduino circuit? Did the Arduino code use the internal pull-up resistor with the 4n35's output? You'll need a resistor somewhere to interface it with a microcontroller.

Comment: Wiring the infrared LED of a 4N35 directly in parallel with the device's LED would have reduced the forward voltage to about 1.4 V and the device's LED would have turned off. You must have had a resistor in series with the IR LED.

Comment: If it worked with an Arduino, why wouldn't it work as-is with an ESP32 or any other MCU?

Comment: Is the OP using the Arduino framework and same code on the ESP32?

Comment: it should work fine/the same.